# How to use where clause through relationships on Eloquent statically?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel app I have 3 model classes: `Project`, `Task` and `TaskState`. This is basically the code:

`Project.php`

```
class Project extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }
}
```

`Task.php`

```
class Task extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
    }

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TaskState');
    }
}
```

`TaskState.php`

```
class TaskState extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
    }
}
```

I want to filter all tasks on "open" state from a project. Now I'm using the join clause, but **I want to know if it's possible using something like this**:

```
Task::where('state.name', 'open')->get();
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work, because using the dot on where clauses is possible from "inside" the class. For example, from a `getFooAtribute()` method:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function getOpenTasksSumAttribute()
    {
        // This works. Why not from outside?
        return $this->tasks->where('state.name', 'open')->count();
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
The `whereHas()` method solved my problem.

Also the above `getOpenTasksSumAttribute()` method didn't work in fact, but it worked when I changed the `Task` model to `return this->belongsTo('App\TaskState');`.

Comment: What's the SQL result of `Task::where('state.name', 'open')->get();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think any of them should work. Usually the approach is to use `whereHas()` to do conditional for relationships.

```
Task::whereHas('state', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'open');
})->get();
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong there too but the `whereHas` method whas exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: There was an error in the syntax, but else update your question and i will look into it :)